# Avoiding object creation with SQL Alchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

Short question: How do I avoid object creation when fetching from an SQL Alchemy-backed object?

Situation:
SQL Alchemy: I have an ORM object (declarative base) Objects backed by a table with columns uid, name, etc. Now I would like to create a separate table ObjectProps which uses uid as a foreign, primary key , and then an additional Text field. Additionally, it is setup as a relationship such that ObjectProps has a relationship called props with ObjectProps (uselist=False, backref="object").

Long question: How can I retrieve ObjectProps's Text attribute/column via props *without* generating the ObjectProps ORM object? I would ideally like to avoid the object creation overhead since ideally I just want to retrieve the column's value without creating an entire ObjectProps.

Presumably the solution will require mixing the ORM Layer with the SQL Layer. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything the ORM loads when you use `relationship()` is going to be an object.   It depends here on if the issue is the performance and memory overhead of loading ObjectProps, or if it's just that you want to access the columns in a nice way without "seeing" ObjectProps.  For the latter, this is easy using the association proxy and we have [examples](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/examples.html#module-examples.vertical) of this.   For the former, yes you'd need to use core if you just want a raw SELECT.   You can perhaps use a [descriptor](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/glossary.html?highlight=descriptor#term-descriptors).  Below is one that does a SELECT from a table when first accessed:

```
class MyObject(Base):
    # ...

    _properties = None

    @property
    def my_properties(self):
        if self._properties:
            return self._properties
        self._properties = dict(
               (row.key, row.value) for row in 
               object_session(self).execute(
                     object_table.select().
                     where(object_table.c.parent_id == self.id)
               )
        )
        return self._properties
```

There's some rudimental memoization going on above.  If you wanted to do that, and link `_properties` to the lifecycle of the object, you can link it to events like [expire](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.InstanceEvents.expire) so that you'd know when to clear it out.

Answer (score 1):

I divide querying into: guering of objects and quering of data like SQL does.
Try look at 
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/tutorial.html#selecting
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html
Using quering:

```
.session.query(
        UserModel.id,
        UserModel.username,
        UserModel.email,
        UserModel.best_friend_id,
        FUserModel.username.label('friend_username'),
        func.count().label('friends')
      )\
      .select_from(UserModel)\
```

....